# Is there any option to connect (in JAVA) Oracle database like SQLite ?

Tags: java, database, oracle, sqlite

Is there any option to connect Oracle database like(SQLite):

```
 Connection conn = null;
    try {
        // db parameters
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/db/chinook.db";
        // create a connection to the database
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established.");
```

I want that my Oracle database to be in the program directory like here:

```
 String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/db/chinook.db";
```

Oracle DB Connetion:

```
try{     
     Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","oracle");
     return con;
```

I do not want to run localhost like

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","oracle");
```

Comment: Why?............You don't want to run localhost like .........?

Comment: My instructor want my program on CD. Last time I used SQLite with file "xxx.db" in project.

Comment: No, oracle cannot run with just a file on the filesystem and no external processes.

Comment: oracle is not sqlite so you can't use it like a file

Comment: Ok, I am just asking.

Comment: Maybe you could use Apache Derby, it can be embedded into a Java program.